# Selenium - create a CSS selector for an element that does not have a child

Tags: html, selenium, css-selectors

Here is the HTML of my tool. Each `<li` is a button for a page. Once I click the page number, that element will no longer have the child `<a`. So in the below example, page 2 is selected.

```
<span class="pagingWidget"
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="paginate-page" href="javascript:;">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>
      <a class="paginate-page" href="javascript:;">3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="paginate-page" href="javascript:;">4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </span>
```

I want to create an object that will always select the page element that is selected. So I want `span.pagingWidget > ul > li`, that does NOT have a child of `<a`. Is that possible with the negation CSS pseudo-class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're attempting to do is not possible through CSS alone.

The closest thing to what you're describing is the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo class but that is used to select elements that are *completely* empty.

Comment: The question was mistakenly tagged [css] - it does not actually involve CSS styling. I have fixed it. Your statement about it not being possible using just a single CSS selector holds true though.

Comment: CSS selectors are a part of CSS, though, so my answer is still valid, no? Also, can whoever downvoted provide their reasoning for doing so?

Comment: Only the part involving selectors is. Selenium is a web testing tool - there is no styling involved.

Comment: OK, will edit to remove the alternative solution and just leave the first paragraph. I admit, I'm completely unfamiliar with Selenium.

Comment: FWIW, I noticed the downvote, but that was someone else - I upvoted based on the first paragraph.

Comment: Don't worry, given your comments and mod status, I didn't think it was you ;) Thanks for the upvote :)